# How to randomly change the signs of some of the elements in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, random

Given a numpy array

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random
N = 5
x = random(N)
```

How to randomly multiply a subset of (some of the elements in) `x` by `-1` in order to change the sign of some of the elements in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
import random
x = [each*random.choice([-1,1]) for each in x]
```

In one go:

```
x = [each*random.choice([-1,1]) for each in random(N)]
```

where `random(N)` is a random number gemerator generating `N` random numbers, ie it can be `numpy.random.random`, as in the Question's example.

Comment: I like this. how can it be changed to a stand-alone generator, rather than being a second-step transformation of `x`? too bad `random.random` doesn't give negative elements

Comment: @develarist `x = random(N) * 2 - 1`? (Not *exactly* equivalent, but maybe good enough?)

Answer (score 3):

or this:

```
x = np.where(random(N) > 0.5, -x, x)
```

(you can replace `random(N) > 0.5` with whichever other random rule that suits you...)

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a boolean mask indicating which elements to flip. Then you can do:

```
x[mask] *= -1
```

This method also works with  a fancy index:

```
x[index] *= -1
```

You could also use [`np.negative`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.negative.html) quite efficiently:

```
np.negative(x, where=mask, out=x)
```

This approach is likely the most efficient.

Generating a mask is simple. You can encode a simple condition like

```
mask = np.random.random(N) >= 0.66
```

Or you can use [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to select a random fancy index:

```
index = np.random.choice(N, size=N // 2, replace=False)
```

Finally, you can use some real hacks to do this with XOR. The idea is that IEEE 754 encodes the sign bit in the highest bit of a number. You can flip the sign by flipping that one bit using the Integer representation of the floating point values. This only works for floats of course.

You could tailor the size of your integers to the size of the float, or simply use `np.uint8` with the bits `0x80`. Indices would be scaled by the size of the float.

```
x.view(np.uint8)[index * x.itemsize] ^= 0x80
```

This assumes little-endian byte order. For big-endian, use an offset:

```
x.view(np.uint8)[(index + 1) * x.itemsize - 1] ^= 0x80
```

**Timings**

Here are some benchmarks I ran on my moderately powered laptop:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import repeat

def where(x, mask):
    x = np.where(mask, -x, x)

def mask_(x, mask):
    x[mask] *= -1

def index(x, mask):
    x[np.flatnonzero(mask)] *= -1 

def negat(x, mask):
    np.negative(x, where=mask, out=x)

def xor__(x, mask):
    x.view(np.uint8)[np.flatnonzero(mask) * x.itemsize] ^= 0x80

for E in range(2, 7):
    N = 10**E
    x = np.random.random(N)

    for P in (0.1, 0.5, 0.9):
        mask = np.random.random(N) < P

        print(f'E = {E}, P = {P}:')

        for func in where, mask_, index, negat, xor__:
            B = 10**(7 - E)
            t = min(repeat(lambda: func(x, mask), number=B)) / B
            print(f'{func.__name__}: {t:.3g}')
```

The results, separated by `P`:

```
P = 0.1
+-----+------+---------------------------------------+
|     |      |                  Func                 |
| Exp | Unit +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     |      | where | mask_ | index | negat | xor__ |
+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  2  |  μs  |  4.11 |  6.20 |  12.5 | *3.06 |  14.9 |
|  3  |  μs  |  7.47 |  12.4 |  15.9 | *5.55 |  18.6 |
|  4  |  μs  | *32.3 |  94.0 |  41.6 |  38.9 |  49.8 |
|  5  |  ms  | *.258 |  1.06 |  .582 |  .575 |  .602 |
|  6  |  ms  |  15.7 |  10.5 |  6.44 | *5.87 |  6.57 |
+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

```
P = 0.5
+-----+------+---------------------------------------+
|     |      |                  Func                 |
| Exp | Unit +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     |      | where | mask_ | index | negat | xor__ |
+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  2  |  μs  |  4.11 |  6.53 |  13.0 | *3.48 |  15.4 |
|  3  |  μs  | *7.42 |  17.1 |  20.1 |  9.71 |  26.0 |
|  4  |  μs  | *32.0 |  234. |  140. |  130. |  150. |
|  5  |  ms  | *.268 |  2.41 |  1.27 |  1.43 |  1.36 |
|  6  |  ms  |  15.5 |  27.7 |  20.5 | *14.2 |  21.1 |
+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

```
P = 0.9
+-----+------+---------------------------------------+
|     |      |                  Func                 |
| Exp | Unit +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     |      | where | mask_ | index | negat | xor__ |
+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  2  |  μs  |  4.11 |  6.23 |  13.2 | *3.13 |  15.7 |
|  3  |  μs  |  7.81 |  15.0 |  23.6 | *6.40 |  28.4 |
|  4  |  μs  | *31.5 |  116. |  104. |  54.8 |  130. |
|  5  |  ms  | *.263 |  1.24 |  .882 |  .612 |  1.02 |
|  6  |  ms  |  16.6 |  18.4 |  21.0 | *6.24 |  22.9 |
+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Conclusion: for small arrays (<10^4 elements), and large arrays (>10^6 elements), `np.negative` is generally the fastest approach. For the sweet spot around 10^3-10^4 elements, `np.where` dominates. When comparing times, keep in mind that methods `index` and `xor__` depend on index arrays. If that is an input for you, subtract off the times required to call `np.flatnonzero`.

In all cases, the proportion of flipped elements determined by `P` does not affect the outcome much.

For reference, I've also timed the differences between using `np.random.choice` to create indices versus using a mask. These times are a bit approximate, since the results of the two operations are not exactly identical:

```
def thresh(n, p):
    return np.flatnonzero(np.random.random(n) < p)

def choice(n, p):
    return np.random.choice(n, size=round(n * p), replace=False)

for E in range(2, 7):
    N = 10**E
    for P in (0.1, 0.5, 0.9):
        print(f'E = {E}, P = {P}:')
        for func in thresh, choice:
            B = 10**(7 - E)
            t = min(repeat(lambda: func(N, P), number=B)) / B
            print(f'{func.__name__}: {t:.3g}')
```

Timings (aggregated into a table):

```
+-----+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|     |      |                          P                          |
|     |      +-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Exp | Unit |       0.1       |       0.5       |        0.9      |
|     |      +--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     |      | thresh | choice | thresh | choice | thresh | choice |
+-----+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  2  |  μs  |  14.8  |  35.2  |  15.3  |  34.9  |  14.7  |  34.9  |
|  3  |  μs  |  34.2  |  75.8  |  40.6  |  75.5  |  34.8  |  76.0  |
|  4  |  μs  |  214.  |  494.  |  267.  |  494.  |  206.  |  494.  |
|  5  |  ms  |  1.96  |  4.60  |  2.48  |  4.60  |  1.89  |  4.60  | 
|  6  |  ms  |  26.1  |  50.1  |  34.5  |  50.3  |  30.7  |  50.2  |
+-----+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Thresholding a random array and calling `np.flatnonzero` is always ~2x faster  than using `np.random.choice`. The former approach allows you to replicate masks exactly, while the latter allows you to set the exact number of flipped elements.

Comment: @HeapOverflow. I've fixed my wording a bit to exclude fancy indexing from the ufunc route. Also added a new over-the-top approach

Comment: I tested a bit and except for the `np.negative` one, all of these were *slower* than Julien's.

Comment: @HeapOverflow. How big of an array size? Fundamentally, they all have the same complexity, so I guess dealing with a boolean index has more overhead than just breezing through an array and negating the whole thing. I've updated my wording. Thanks for running benchmarks

Comment: A million elements, see [results and code](https://repl.it/repls/GrossBusySystemsoftware#main.py).

Comment: @HeapOverflow. Neat. I don't think it matters much, but I think you should remove the mask generation from the test. A) user likely wants some custom stuff, B) you ensure that all tests are flipping the same elements by passing in the mask

Comment: [For 1000 elements](https://repl.it/repls/LightpinkInformalLinkedlist#main.py), Julien's seems to be the fastest. Hmm, I'm measuring with `number=10` or `number=10000` (i.e., with multiple/many masks) and `repeat=5` (default), I'd think that further reduces any influence that different masks might have. I could take it out to measure just the application of the masks, but I wouldn't be able to compare the mask-solutions with the index-solutions that way (since I think computing `index` is significantly more expensive).

Comment: @HeapOverflow. That makes sense. I would bench those as separate categories. Usually, a user will have a mask or a selection of indices, not both. I would only benchmark the part where you call flatnonzero or so to convert, since that's no longer a raw input.

Comment: Uh, I don't know flatnonzero  and I'm actually a numpy noob, probably won't do more testing now. The one thing I'd be interested in is why your `np.negative` solution wins against Julien's at a million but loses at a thousand. I suspect Julien's loops over data more often and that hurts cache-wise somehow when the data gets large.

Comment: @HeapOverflow. Here's what I had in mind: https://repl.it/repls/WelloffTrustingPlanes#main.py. `np.where` is still the way to go

Comment: Looking now. Could you update or remove the timing results there?

Comment: @HeapOverflow. I'm looking at how it runs, and I'm getting the feeling that running benchmarks on a shared machine with weird scheduling like that is a bad idea. I'll post timings from my laptop momentarily. In the answer. I've been on mobile until now.

Comment: Yeah, I only included the repl.it times because they looked fairly stable here and painted the same picture as my PC's times. Still, please remove the times in that repl.it, as they're not from the code below them, so that could be misleading.

Comment: @HeapOverflow. OK added benchmarks to my question. On the laptops, timings were extremely consistent between rounds, so I dropped rounds. Also, `f6` is a workaround only to be used on big-endian architectures, so I dropped it. Enjoy

Comment: What's up with printing all those empty lines? :-). More importantly, you're not doing it right, shouldn't give the `index` solutions the `index` precomputation for free. Precomputing `mask` before the benchmarking is ok, as all solutions use it (directly or indirectly). But precomputing `index` isn't.

Comment: `number=10**7 // N` might be better, would get better results for small N and would require less patience for large N :-) (Btw took back my upvote for now, as I find the current benchmark misleading as described above)

Comment: @HeapOverflow. OK I'll compromise by setting the seed in each case. That way we're guaranteed to have the same mask/index. It's still a bit misleading, but should be ok. Will update soon.

Comment: Hmm, like I said, I think precomputing the mask is ok. I'd just move the mask-to-index calculation into the functions that use it.

Comment: @HeapOverflow. I've updated the timings, the computations, and added a benchmark for the different index generation methods. Enjoy!

Comment: I really did enjoy that :-). Neat tables. Created by hand, or is there a tool for that?

Comment: @HeapOverflow. By hand. I was bored :) Next level is to make a tool for that...